# (a public constructor with no arguments) (tr.dailyplus.berkaykara.fragments.DatePickerFragment) [ValidFragment]

Tags: android

Hello I encounter this error while the hats come from?

Error:Error: This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (tr.dailyplus.berkaykara.fragments.DatePickerFragment) [ValidFragment]

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callback;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param callback - callback function when a date has been selected
 */
public DatePickerFragment(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), callback, year, month, day);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Fragments have to provide a no-arg constructor. By providing your own constructor, compiler won't provide default constructor unless you explicitly write one.

On a side note, instead of providing parameters via constructor you should provide a creator function that returns a fragment and sets an argument Bundle for it, since it's preserved.

If you need to implement callbacks, then you could make your activity implement an interface, and in your fragment cast context to this interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the default constructor. You need to provide a default constructor which accepts no params.

If you need a way to communicate with the fragment, then the best way is to implement an interface and use the parent Activity to communicate.

See the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) on how it's done. Specifically look in the "Creating event callbacks to the activity" section on how it's done.